# How to handle Back Button in nested fragments of Viewpager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, back-button, fragment-backstack

According to [image: THIS PICTURE] I have an Activity which contains **ViewPager** which loads three fragments:

- RootA
- RootB
- RootC

**RootA** loads another fragment which named as *FragA*.

**RootB** loads another fragment which named as *FragB*.

**RootC** loads another fragment which named as *FragC*.

```
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragA());
fragTransaction.commit();
```

**FragA** has a button named as ButtonA to load *FragAA*.

**FragB** has a button named as ButtonB to load *FragBB*.

**FragC** has a button named as ButtonC to load *FragCC*.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragAA, "FragAA");
fragTransaction.addToBackStack("FragAA");
fragTransaction.commit();
```

I run my App and in the first tab, I press ButtonA. FragAA will be shown. Now I swipe to the second tab and press ButtonB and go to FragBB and then I swipe to the third tab and press ButtonC and go to FragCC.

After that, I swipe to the second tab and then I swipe to the first tab again without any clicking. then I press Back Button. By the **first back pressing** *FragCC* will be closed (will put out of BackStack), by the **second back pressing** *FragBB* will be closed, and by the **third back pressing** *FragAA* will be closed.

But I want my app to close child of current tab not to close fragments according to the **BackStack**.

I mean the Back Button should close *FragAA* because I am in the first tab and I pressed Back Button in the **first tab**!

How can I do it?

Comment: Look at [this blog](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-fragment-navigation-pattern). May be you will find something useful...

Comment: @isabsent: I studied that article. It has many useful information but not about my problem.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @user987362 I Check fragments' Visibility, manually.